# jQuery issue copying script

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to get this script to work that I found over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MJ9Zw/
It does not sort.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>  <html lang="en"> 
 <head>         <script
 type="text/javascript"
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var table = $('table');

     $('#facility_header, #city_header')
         .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
         .each(function(){
             var th = $(this),
                 thIndex = th.index(),
                 inverse = false;
             th.click(function(){
                 table.find('td').filter(function(){
                     return $(this).index() === thIndex;
                 }).sortElements(function(a, b){
                     return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
                         inverse ? -1 : 1
                         : inverse ? 1 : -1;
                 }, function(){
                    // parentNode is the element we want to move
                     return this.parentNode; 
                 });
                 inverse = !inverse;
             });
         });

    </script>     
 </head> 
   <body>    
     <table>
         <tr>    
             <th id="facility_header">Facility name</th>    
             <th>Phone #</th>    
             <th id="city_header">City</th>    
             <th>Speciality</th>    
         </tr>    
         <tr>    
             <td>CCC</td>    
             <td>00001111</td>    
             <td>Amsterdam</td>   
             <td>GGG</td>    
         </tr>    
         <tr>    
             <td>JJJ</td>    
             <td>55544444</td>    
             <td>London</td>    
             <td>MMM</td>    
         </tr>    
         <tr>    
             <td>AAA</td>    
             <td>33332222</td>    
             <td>Paris</td>    
             <td>RRR</td>    
         </tr>
 </table>    
 </body>    
    </html>
```

Edit:
I know this looks silly, but I have been staring at this for a couple hours.
 I know I am missing something obvious, but I have know idea where it is. I have tried two or three different jQuery libraries, but that did not fix it. I have copied it half a dozen times.  I apologize in advance for pasting the whole thing, but I am not seeing it. I know I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: Please use comment blocks _(`{}` button or start code/markup with four spaces on every line)_. Also please don't just kerslap your code here. Let us know what you've tried, what worked and what didn't work.

Comment: Good for you! Just run it on a browser

Comment: I did run it on Chrome and FF and it is not working.

Comment: @Roger - I think what the others above are trying to suggest is that you tell us *what* isn't working about it. Pasting a great swathe of code & saying "fix it" isn't the best way to go about getting your questions answered.

Comment: Alconja, I edited the post. Y'all are right I could have explained the issue much better.  As far as pasting the whole thing though, I did that because I simply don't know where I am going wrong; I have been staring/playing witht it for a couple hours.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the javascript in a $(document).ready({...})? Could be a timing issue.

Comment: Babak, yes I did try on a prvious version. I just tried again with the above version; it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the include of [the `jquery.sortElements.js` script](https://raw.github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js), which you can see registered in the jsfiddle page under "manage resources" section on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/raw/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js"></script>
```

to your page?

Tip: try adding `/show` to Fiddle URLs, view source and copy.